# Unable to install Microsoft Visio 2016 on server 2012

Tags: office365, visio

We had successfully installed Microsoft Office 2016 on new server,But we were unable to install Microsoft Visio 2016 on this machine.We were getting following error:"We found a problem! 
We're sorry, Office Click-to-Run installer encountered a problem because you have these Windows Installer based Office programs installed on your computer. 
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 
Click-to-Run and Windows Installer editions of Office programs don't get along for this version, so you can only have one type installed at a time. Please try installing the Windows Installer edition of Office instead, or uninstall your other Windows Installer based Office programs and try this installation again.

[image: Click here to see error message]

Answer (score 2):

You'll get this error message if you try to install an Office 365 product or a standalone Office 2013 or Office 2016 application (like Access, Visio, Project, Skype for Business, or OneDrive for Business) when you have the 2013 or 2016 versions of Microsoft Office Professional Plus or Microsoft Office Standard already installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced exactly the same warning (*...Office Click-to-Run installer encountered a problem because you have these Windows Installer based Office programs installed on your computer...*), and succeeded to install Visio 2016 to PC that is already installed with MS Office 2016 Professional Plus. Here is the detailed solution.

**Root of the problem:** Microsoft prevented Click-to-Run (C2R) edition and Windows Installer (MSI) edition to run simultaneously in the same computer.

**Workaround hint:** C2R checks whether there is already an installed MSI edition (such as MS Office 2016 Professional Plus) in the PC. So, somehow if I hide MSI edition (while still being installed in the PC) from C2R checker, I can install C2R Visio to MSI-installed MS Office Pro Plus machine!

**Inspiration for the solution:**
http://woshub.com/how-to-hide-installed-programs-from-programs-and-features/
thenicnic's 12.05.2018 brilliant approach:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/de-DE/344c975d-1d36-4338-8f7a-0f0eb685234c/office-2016-msi-installer-volume-license-incompatible-with-visioproject-2016-from-msdn-click-to?forum=Office2016setupdeploy

**Solution (step by step):**
My PC: 64-bit Windows 10; installed with 32-bit MS Office 2016 Professional Plus
Installation of Visio 2016 Professional Plus:
**1.** Hide MS Office 2016 Professional Plus from C2R checker:

- Go to the registry path:
  If you have 64-bit operating system (OS) PC and 32-bit Office:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office16.PROPLUS
  If you have 64-bit operating system (OS) PC and 64-bit Office:
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office16.PROPLUS
- Add a DWORD value named **SystemComponent** and set it to **1**.
  Upon addition, Office 2016 Pro Plus becomes invisible in "Control Panel - Programs and Features" (though it still remains installed in the PC and thereby deceives C2R checker!).
- Enjoy the trick a little bit (set SystemComponent to 0 and see Office 2016 Pro Plus becomes visible upon F5 (refresh) in "Control Panel - Programs and Features". Now, turn back to our job, i.e., set SystemComponent to 1 once again)
- Now, one can install Visio 2016 with the C2R installer.

**2.** Download Office 2016 Deployment Tool (officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe).
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026267/office-office-2016-deployment-tool

Run officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe. This creates a folder named *OfficeDeploymentTool* with files *setup.exe* and *configure.xml*.

**3.** Open configure.xml (with NotePad), save it as InstallVisio.xml, delete all its content, and put the following code into InstallVisio.xml file:

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" >
    <Product ID="VisioProXVolume" PIDKEY="69WXN-MBYV6-22PQG-3WGHK-RM6XC">
        <Language ID="tr-tr" />
     </Product>
   </Add>  
</Configuration>
```

Note that this is for Turkish Visio, the one who wants English Visio must keep the PIDKEY same, but must set **en-us** in the above Language ID part.

**4.** Run Office Deployment Tool to install Visio 2016 Pro Plus:
To install Visio (specified in InstallVisio.xml file), Open Command Prompt change directory and come to the folder where setup.exe of OfficeDeploymentTool is located.
(in my PC, I put officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe to D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition, upon its run, setup.exe and configure.exe was created in D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition\OfficeDeploymentTool. Hence, I came to D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition\OfficeDeploymentTool in Command Prompt).
Run the following command:

```
setup.exe /configure InstallVisio.xml
```

**5.** Installation is successfully made and at the end a message was shown:
https : // prnt.sc / k2u256

PS 1: Those who want MS Office 2016 Pro Plus to be seen in "Control Panel - Programs and Features" should set SystemComponent value to **0** or remove the added registry key (i.e., SystemComponent).

PS 2: I downloaded VisioProRetail.img (4,341,036 KB) and mount it as E, but did not use it in the process. I think that with the above configuration .xml file, Visio was automatically downloaded from Microsoft servers. The resulting successful install message seems to say so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Microsoft has changed how Office products are managed an not very clear on how to install Visio if you are running 2016 via MSI installs.  The error message does not explain a solution but only why you can't. The same goes for most of Microsoft's support. Using the Office Deployment Tool really isn't much help either.

I have Visio via MSDN but with no way to install it on my main machine I had to **resort to using a VM**. :-(  Using the Office Deployment Tool (ODT) I was able to install Visio 2016 on my Server 2012 VM.  I know that's not the solution most people are looking for but that's as far as I was able to get to.

Their may have been others that managed to trick the OS and Office to run both a 365 product and stand alone, however from what I read via Microsoft help forums they needed to call tech support which eventually gave them access to an MSI that is not available on the Microsoft Visio site.

Answer (score -1):

The problem should be explained well enough by the error description- it's expecting the Windows Installer version of Visio 2016.

Please refer to the [Office 2016 Deployment Guides for Admins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303401%28v=office.16%29.aspx) for a full reference of your deployment options.