# Microsoft Visio/Project Click-to-Run (C2R) install via Powershell

Tags: powershell, visio

I have been trying to install Microsoft Visio C2R using PowerShell but have been unsuccessful.

This is the code:

```
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

    {
    Start-Process -FilePath $ScriptRoot\Setup.exe -ArgumentList "/configure configuration.xml" -Wait -PassThru
    }
```

Below is the .xml config file created with the Office Deployment Tool (ODT)

```
<Configuration>
    <Add>
        <Product ID="VisioProXVolume" > 
            <Language ID="en-us" />
        </Product>
    </Add>
    <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
    <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
    <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
    <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
    <Property Name="PinIconsToTaskbar" Value="FALSE" />
</Configuration>
```

It appears like the install begins but then nothing happens. I suspect that setup.exe is not getting the -ArgumentList

The Log reads:

```
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.824 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Activity    bjtct   Medium  ActivityStarted {"Name": "Office.Telemetry.ProcessIdleQueueJob", "CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3", "ProcessIdentifier": "Setup.exe_16.0.8528.3000_X86_{7E634127-F007-4622-A730-D4A3322DC95A}"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.824 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  OfficeTelemetry_RuleProcessing  axbjw   Medium  OTele_ETW_TDC_LoadingRulesStarted {"ETW_EventId": 119, "ETW_Keywords": 4}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.824 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Activity    bjtct   Medium  ActivityStarted {"Name": "Office.Telemetry.LoadXmlRules", "CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3.1", "ProcessIdentifier": "Setup.exe_16.0.8528.3000_X86_{7E634127-F007-4622-A730-D4A3322DC95A}"}
03/14/2018 12:40:58.824 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Telemetry Rules Engine  bcdgv   Monitorable Unrecognized category specified in UlsCategorySeveritySource {"Category": "NexusTenantTokenApphost"}
03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  OfficeTelemetry_PerfMetrics axbjw   Medium  RuleFieldNamesImpact {"ETW_EventId": 196, "ETW_Keywords": 128, "cbMemory": 5900, "count": 182}
03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  OfficeTelemetry_RuleProcessing  axbjw   Medium  OTele_ETW_TDC_LoadingRulesEnded {"ETW_EventId": 120, "ETW_Keywords": 4}
03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Activity    bjtcw   Medium  ActivityEnded {"Name": "Office.Telemetry.LoadXmlRules", "CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3.1", "ProcessIdentifier": "Setup.exe_16.0.8528.3000_X86_{7E634127-F007-4622-A730-D4A3322DC95A}"}

    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Telemetry Event biyhq   Medium  SendEvent {"EventName": "Office.Telemetry.LoadXmlRules", "Flags": 16843009, "InternalSequenceNumber": 4, "Time": "2018-03-14T12:40:58Z", "Contract": "Office.System.Activity", "Activity.CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3.1", "Activity.Duration": 16138, "Activity.Count": 1, "Activity.AggMode": 0, "Activity.Success": true, "Activity.Result.Code": 0, "Activity.Result.Type": "HRESULT"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Telemetry Rules Engine  bd3fw   Medium  Loaded rule list. {"Rules": "606.1 615.0 616.0 620.0 622.0 623.0 625.0 626.0 627.1 629.0 630.3 631.0 633.0 634.0 635.0 636.3 637.0 642.0 643.4 644.3 645.4 646.4 647.8 648.3 649.11 652.0 662.0 669.0 671.1 675.0 682.0 685.0 120100.2 120103.9 120119.0 120122.0 120123.1 120402.10 224900.0 224901.7 224902.2 230104.0 230153.0 230156.0 230157.0 340002.12 340008.0 ", "BatchCount": 47, "TotalCount": 47, "HadRuleFileAtBoot": true}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Telemetry Rules Engine  bd3fx   Medium  Loaded rule count. {"Count": 47, "HadRuleFileAtBoot": true}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  OfficeTelemetry_RuleProcessing  axbjw   Medium  OTele_ETW_RuleProcessing_RuleMetadataWritten {"ETW_EventId": 174, "ETW_Keywords": 4, "Count": 0}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  OfficeTelemetry_RuleProcessing  axbjw   Medium  Otele_ETW_TDC_TimerSet {"ETW_EventId": 184, "ETW_Keywords": 4, "TimerInterval": 60000}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Activity    bjtcw   Medium  ActivityEnded {"Name": "Office.Telemetry.ProcessIdleQueueJob", "CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3", "ProcessIdentifier": "Setup.exe_16.0.8528.3000_X86_{7E634127-F007-4622-A730-D4A3322DC95A}"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Telemetry Event biyhq   Medium  SendEvent {"EventName": "Office.Telemetry.ProcessIdleQueueJob", "Flags": 16843009, "InternalSequenceNumber": 5, "Time": "2018-03-14T12:40:58Z", "Contract": "Office.System.Activity", "Activity.CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.3", "Activity.Duration": 25959, "Activity.Count": 1, "Activity.AggMode": 0}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Activity    bjtct   Medium  ActivityStarted {"Name": "Office.Experimentation.TasFetch", "CV": "J0FjfgfwIkanMNSjMi3JWg.4", "ProcessIdentifier": "Setup.exe_16.0.8528.3000_X86_{7E634127-F007-4622-A730-D4A3322DC95A}"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.TasEndpoint", "TreatmentValue": "https://client-office365-tas.msedge.net/ab?", "TreatmentSource": 1}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.3rdPartyFlightingEnabled", "TreatmentValue": "true", "TreatmentSource": 11}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.SendChannelInformation", "TreatmentValue": "true", "TreatmentSource": 11}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.SendUserIdToEcs", "TreatmentValue": "false", "TreatmentSource": 1}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.SendInstallTypeTas", "TreatmentValue": "true", "TreatmentSource": 11}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.840 SETUP (0x1758)  0x1504  Experiment Liblet   bse1v   Medium  Feature Query Status {"FeatureName": "Microsoft.Office.Experimentation.CheckConnectivity", "TreatmentValue": "false", "TreatmentSource": 1}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  aqkhc   Medium  InitLogging {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "{\"AppVVersion\":\"0.0\",\"Bitness\":\"32\",\"CommandLine\":\"/configure configuration.xml \",\"ExeVer\":\"16.0.8528.3000\",\"IntegrityLevel\":\"0x2000\",\"Locale\":\"2057\",\"ModulePath\":\"C:\\\\Source\\\\Microsoft_Visio_Pro_2016_C2R_VL\\\\Setup.exe\",\"OSVersion\":\"10.0\",\"ProcessType\":\"ODT\",\"ProcessorArch\":\"9\",\"ProductType\":\"1\",\"SecuritySessionId\":\"1\"}"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  b0fkw   Medium  wWinMain {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "Unable to set audience Id as bitfield didn't exist"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    arql8   Medium  Args::ParseArgument: Parsing commandline.
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    arqmb   Medium  Args::Load: Have Admin scenario
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    arql9   Medium  Args::GetNextArgument: Next argument: /configure
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    arql9   Medium  Args::GetNextArgument: Next argument: configuration.xml
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    aoh7y   Medium  Args::GetConfigFile: config file: configuration.xml
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    appfq   Medium  Args::Load: product release id: none  culture: en-us
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    apvr9   Medium  TrySetUserRegistry::TrySetAttemptGetKey: Setting Attempt Get Key for none
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  ayef6   Medium  TrySetUserRegistry::TrySetLicenseTokenOrKey {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "No key or token found for none"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  buhx5   Medium  DetermineCentennialInstallEligibility::HandleStateAction {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "Eligibility Check Skipped."}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  buhx6   Medium  DetermineCentennialInstallEligibility::HandleStateAction {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "Force C2R or empty."}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  buhya   Medium  DetermineCentennialInstallEligibility::HandleStateAction {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "Install Status : {'status':'1'}"}
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    aoh76   Medium  HandleCommandLineAction::HandleStateAction: Not OOD scenario nor showing ODT help, check for elevation.
    03/14/2018 12:40:58.856 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    aoh8i   Medium  TryGetElevation::HandleStateAction: Need to get elevation.
    03/14/2018 12:41:03.104 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    aoh8j   Medium  TryGetElevation::HandleStateAction: Succesfully ran eleveated.
    03/14/2018 12:41:08.350 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run    aoh72   Medium  ExitBootStateMachine::HandleStateAction: Bootstrapper workflow exiting with result: 0x0
    03/14/2018 12:41:08.350 SETUP (0x1758)  0x620   Click-To-Run General Telemetry  arqpm   Medium  AdminBootstrapper::Main {"MachineId": "7aaf6283e7d28f45932e66ce5de7eff7", "SessionID": "d282aea9-ad15-4e3d-b4de-8b8b919a8ea2", "GeoID": 242, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "0.0", "ContextData": "AdminBootstrapper::Main: Installation came back with 0."}
```

Comment: I don't know the product, but the log shows that the parameters are recognized. Maybe you need to add the full path to the xml and not only the name of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @guiwhatsthat

I modified the code per below: 

'Start-Process -FilePath $scriptroot\Setup.exe -ArgumentList "/CONFIGURE C:\Source\Microsoft_Visio_Pro_2016_C2R_VL\configuration.xml"'

This did do an install. Now the difficulty I have is the software will be deployed via SCCM so when it hits a machine it will have a different folder path per machine; when the package downloads, depending on current CCM cache content.

Answer (score 4):

The Command Prompt suffices. No need to use Powershell.

I solved this question yesterday:
[Unable to install Microsoft Visio 2016 on server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144996/unable-to-install-microsoft-visio-2016-on-server-2012)

I have faced exactly the same warning (*...Office Click-to-Run installer encountered a problem because you have these Windows Installer based Office programs installed on your computer...*), and succeeded to install Visio 2016 to PC that is already installed with MS Office 2016 Professional Plus. Here is the detailed solution.

**Root of the problem:** Microsoft prevented Click-to-Run (C2R) edition and Windows Installer (MSI) edition to run simultaneously in the same computer.

**Workaround hint:** C2R checks whether there is already an installed MSI edition (such as MS Office 2016 Professional Plus) in the PC. So, somehow if I hide MSI edition (while still being installed in the PC) from C2R checker, I can install C2R Visio to MSI-installed MS Office Pro Plus machine!

**Inspiration for the solution:**
http://woshub.com/how-to-hide-installed-programs-from-programs-and-features/
thenicnic's 12.05.2018 brilliant approach:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/de-DE/344c975d-1d36-4338-8f7a-0f0eb685234c/office-2016-msi-installer-volume-license-incompatible-with-visioproject-2016-from-msdn-click-to?forum=Office2016setupdeploy

**Solution (step by step):**
My PC: 64-bit Windows 10; installed with 32-bit MS Office 2016 Professional Plus
Installation of Visio 2016 Professional Plus:
**1.** Hide MS Office 2016 Professional Plus from C2R checker:

- Go to the registry path:
  If you have 64-bit operating system (OS) PC and 32-bit Office:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office16.PROPLUS
  If you have 64-bit operating system (OS) PC and 64-bit Office:
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office16.PROPLUS
- Add a DWORD value named **SystemComponent** and set it to **1**.
  Upon addition, Office 2016 Pro Plus becomes invisible in "Control Panel - Programs and Features" (though it still remains installed in the PC and thereby deceives C2R checker!).
- Enjoy the trick a little bit (set SystemComponent to 0 and see Office 2016 Pro Plus becomes visible upon F5 (refresh) in "Control Panel - Programs and Features". Now, turn back to our job, i.e., set SystemComponent to 1 once again)
- Now, one can install Visio 2016 with the C2R installer.

**2.** Download Office 2016 Deployment Tool (officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe).
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026267/office-office-2016-deployment-tool

Run officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe. This creates a folder named *OfficeDeploymentTool* with files *setup.exe* and *configure.xml*.

**3.** Open configure.xml (with NotePad), save it as InstallVisio.xml, delete all its content, and put the following code into InstallVisio.xml file:

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" >
    <Product ID="VisioProXVolume" PIDKEY="69WXN-MBYV6-22PQG-3WGHK-RM6XC">
        <Language ID="tr-tr" />
     </Product>
   </Add>  
</Configuration>
```

Note that this is for Turkish Visio, the one who wants English visio must set **en-us** in the above Language ID part.

**4.** Run Office Deployment Tool to install Visio 2016 Pro Plus:
To install Visio (specified in InstallVisio.xml file), Open Command Prompt change directory and come to the folder where setup.exe of OfficeDeploymentTool is located.
(in my PC, I put officedeploymenttool_10321.33602.exe to D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition, upon its run, setup.exe and configure.exe was created in D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition\OfficeDeploymentTool. Hence, I came to D:\Office2016ClickToRunEdition\OfficeDeploymentTool in Command Prompt).
Run the following command:

```
setup.exe /configure InstallVisio.xml
```

**5.** Installation is successfully made and at the end a message was shown:
https : // prnt.sc / k2u256

PS 1: Those who want MS Office 2016 Pro Plus to be seen in "Control Panel - Programs and Features" should set SystemComponent value to **0** or remove the added registry key (i.e., SystemComponent).

PS 2: I downloaded VisioProRetail.img (4,341,036 KB) and mount it as E, but did not use it in the process. I think that with the above configuration .xml file, Visio was automatically downloaded from Microsoft servers. The resulting successful install message seems to say so.

PS 3: The above .xml file works for Microsoft Visio Professional 2019 as well; the only necessary change is PIDKEY of Visio 2019: i.e., change PIDKEY to be "N2CG9-YD3YK-936X4-3WR82-Q3X4H".

Comment: After a long search on the internet, this answer actually worked. Thanks so much. I did have to uninstall Office 365 Pro after this installation but Visio remained. Also the registry key that worked for me (64-bit Windows, 64-bit Office) was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Office16.PROPLUS